# pycharm does not recognise rest framework

Tags: python, django

I want to use rest_framework in my tutorial django project.

I followed instruction steps and added 'rest_framework' in to settings.py as shown below.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'rest_framework' 
]
```

However pycharm does not recognise the 'rest_framework' and gives an error when I try to run server:

> - Failed to get real commands on module "DjangoProject": python process    died with code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>     "E:\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pycharm_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py",
>     line 25, in 
>        django.setup()   File "D:\DjangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line
>     24, in setup
>        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "D:\DjangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>     line 89, in populate
>        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "D:\DjangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 
>     90, in create
>        module = import_module(entry)   File "D:\DjangoProject\venv\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>     import_module
>        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File 
>     "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>     "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

What would be the reason ?

Comment: Did you install it? Try run this command: `pip install djangorestframework`.

Comment: Yeap I install it.  C:\Users\serka>pip install djangorestframework
Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework in c:\phyton\lib\site-packages

Comment: Yo @SerkanEmreElçi, install djangorestframework in the virtual environment not the global python installation and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189811/oluwafemi-sule

If you got the same problem , you probably installing restframework to your global environment. You have to install it in your virtual machine.

Virtual machine is located in your project folder.
by command prompt (for windows):

- cd YourProjectFolder\venv\Scripts

then activate it. by >>activate command.

then you are in.

Please type your

- pip install djangorestframework

command here.

I hope it will work.

Comment: Not quite, you'll need to _run_ `activate`, as it's a script.  You can't `cd` to it.

Comment: I updated it, in the light of your precious comment. Thanks.